# Mustache.js recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

I am trying to build an html tree using Mustache.js, but it fails throwning an "Maximum call stack size exceeded", probably because an infinite recursion.

What's wrong?

```
var Mustache = require('mustache');

var root = {
    title: 'Gar1',
    children: [{title: 'gar2'}, {title: 'gar3', children: [{title: 'gar4'}]}]
};

var panelTemplate = '{{title}}<ul>{{#children}}<li>{{>panel}}</li>{{/children}}</ul>';

var partials = {panel: panelTemplate};
var output = Mustache.render(panelTemplate, root, partials);


console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 18):

The problem is inherent to the implementation in Mustache.js (disclaimer: not sure if the problem is in the spec itself) as the algorithm looks for a property on its *parent* when it can't find it on the current context.

To explain it briefly: code runs on your template, outputs `Gar1<ul>` and finds a `{{#children}}` tag. Since your context has a children tag it outputs the `<li>` and invokes the partial which will now run on the inner context `{title: 'gar2'}`. When Mustache reaches your `{{#children}}` tag again, it now finds out that the current context has no `children` property, thus it goes one level up where it actually finds your children property and starts recursing (is this a real word?) again on itself like mad.

Two possible solutions:

**1 -** modify your data so that all entries have a `children` property, and when a node should have no children set it to `false` or `null` (not an empty array) like this:

```
var root = {
    title: 'Gar1',
    children: [{title: 'gar2', children: false}, {title: 'gar3', children: [{title: 'gar4', children: false}]}]
};
```

**2 -** use Handlebars instead of Mustache, and wrap the `<ul>` in an `{{#if children}}` tag.

Hope this helps, I know the answer is a bit late since this has been asked.

Comment: Worth knowing: some Mustache implementations accept the `{{# .children}}` syntax, which means "get `children` from the current context, and avoid digging deeper if not present".

Comment: FWIW, the "anchor dot notation" has been proposed to the Mustache spec: https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/52

Answer (score 6):

Here is one object that needs recursion.

#### Object

```
var obj = [
    {
        obj: true,
        key: 'a',
        value: [
            {
                obj: false,
                key: 'a',
                value: 1
            },
            {
                obj: false,
                key: 'b',
                value: 2
            },
            {
                obj: true,
                key: 'c',
                value: [
                    {
                        obj: false,
                        key: 'a',
                        value: 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        obj: false,
        key: 'b',
        value: 4
    }
];
```

#### Template (recursion.html).

```
<!-- root -->
<ul>
    {{#value}}
    <li>
        <!-- object -->
        {{#obj}}
        <span><b>{{key}}</b></span>
        {{>object}}
        {{/obj}}
        <!-- value -->
        {{^obj}}
        <span><b>{{key}}</b> <span>{{value}}</span></span>
        {{/obj}}
    </li>
    {{/value}}
</ul>
```

The first object you pass in is the root it has no `key` only a `value`. If the `value` has a property `obj` set to `true` then it's an object, print out its key and call the template again recursively for its value.
If not an object then no need for recursion, simply print out.

#### Render client side.

```
// html is recursion.html contents
var template = Hogan.compile(html),
    content = template.render({value: obj}, {object: html});
// show the rendered template
$('body').empty().append(content);
```

#### Render server side with Express.js

```
res.render('recursion', {
    value: obj,
    partials: {
        object: 'recursion'
    }
});
```

#### Output of this example

#### http://jsfiddle.net/simo/GYjMY/

Btw I'm using Hogan.js for rendering the template. I don't know whether Mustache.js render supports recursion or not.

Comment: Great example, however the user's question was specific to Mustache.